# Reading in from a file and drawing

Tags: python

The problem I am having involves reading in from a file, and using python's turtle to draw shapes based on what is read in.

The text file looks like this (but no spaces in between the lines):

r 0.0 200.0 50.0 100.0 blue

c 0.0 200.0 40.0 red

p 0.0 200.0 3 40.0 black

the problem is going from a line in the file to something like
r = Rectangle(0.0,200.0,50.0,100.0,"blue")

if the line starts with a "r", use my Rectangle method, if its starts with a "c" use my Circle method (or "p" use Polygon())

I have all the shape methods down I just don't know how to get it from the file to say draw a rectangle(or circle/polygon) at these coordinates with these side lengths and this color. This is what I have so far, but it seems too complicated and is getting messy. Any help or ideas are appreciated, thanks.

```
shapeCollection=[]
with open(name,"r") as f:
    for line in f:
        for i in line.split():
            shapeCollection.append(i)
print(shapeCollection)
for each in shapeCollection:
    if each == "r":
        #(xCor) = each+1
    elif each == "c":
        #
    elif each == "p":
        #
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do something like this

```
for line in f:
 inp = line.split()
 x = float(inp[1])
 y = float(inp[2])

 if(inp[0] == 'r'):
  DrawRectangle(x,y,float(inp[3]),float(inp[4]),inp[5])
```

This just basically shows how to parse the input. It is pretty simple and you see how it could easily be applied to the other 2 cases.